# How can I remove breakpoint ntdll!DbgBreakPoint+0x1 in WinDbg

Tags: windbg

I'm debugging a program that's crashing with WinDbg set as my post-mortem debugger.  I have set a breakpoint at address 77f7f571.  When it's triggered, I used to get the following:

```
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for C:\WINDOWS\System32\ntdll.dll - 
ntdll!DbgBreakPoint+0x1:
```

Then I followed the instructions from http://www.osronline.com/ShowThread.cfm?link=178221, and now I just get

```
ntdll!DbgBreakPoint+0x1:
```

I'd like to remove this breakpoint, but I can't get it to list or delete.  There's no output for bl, nor for bc or bd:

```
0:002> bl 
0:002> bc * 
0:002> bd *
```

Comment: That's a hard-coded breakpoint, not a debugger breakpoint. Somebody called `DebugBreak` which means "Force a break into the debugger."

Comment: I'm the only one on the newly created VM, so it was me that did whatever I did.  I'm pretty sure I added this with bp 77f7f571, and then I cause an Access Violation, and the crashing program starts the debugger.

Comment: And now I know what you meant.  I installed a fresh VM, and found that this fresh install also did ntdll!DbgBreakPoint+0x1:, ergo the program itself is catching the problem and calling to ntdll.dll.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a line based breakpoint but looks like a manual call to `DebugBreak()` like in the following program:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "windows.h"    
int _tmain()
{
    DebugBreak();
    return 0;
}
```

Internally, the method will throw an exception. To control whether WinDbg stops due to the exception, use `sxe bpe` to stop and `sxi bpe` to ignore the exception.

To try this, compile above application and run it under WinDbg (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>). At the inital breakpoint, take over the control:

```
(1c2c.6a8): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
eax=00000000 ebx=00000000 ecx=779d0000 edx=0020e218 esi=fffffffe edi=00000000
eip=773e12fb esp=0038f9e8 ebp=0038fa14 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000246
ntdll!LdrpDoDebuggerBreak+0x2c:
773e12fb cc              int     3

0:000> sxe bpe; g
(1c2c.6a8): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for DebugBreak.exe
eax=cccccccc ebx=7efde000 ecx=00000000 edx=00000001 esi=0038fd44 edi=0038fe10
eip=74d5322c esp=0038fd40 ebp=0038fe10 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na pe nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000206
KERNELBASE!DebugBreak+0x2:
74d5322c cc              int     3

0:000> g
eax=00000000 ebx=00000000 ecx=00000000 edx=00000000 esi=77442100 edi=774420c0
eip=7735fd02 esp=0038fd78 ebp=0038fd94 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000246
ntdll!ZwTerminateProcess+0x12:
7735fd02 83c404          add     esp,4
```

After this experiment, type `.restart`. Then repeat the experiment with `sxi bpe`:

```
(109c.1c1c): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
eax=00000000 ebx=00000000 ecx=be9e0000 edx=0009e028 esi=fffffffe edi=00000000
eip=773e12fb esp=002ff890 ebp=002ff8bc iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000246
ntdll!LdrpDoDebuggerBreak+0x2c:
773e12fb cc              int     3

0:000> sxi bpe; g
eax=00000000 ebx=00000000 ecx=00000000 edx=00000000 esi=77442100 edi=774420c0
eip=7735fd02 esp=002ffc20 ebp=002ffc3c iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000246
ntdll!ZwTerminateProcess+0x12:
7735fd02 83c404          add     esp,4
```

As you can see, WinDbg did not stop at `KERNELBASE!DebugBreak+0x2` due to the exception any more.