# How to skip a hard-coded breakpoint with Windbg (C ++ )?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, windbg

I have the same problem in  : [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9099586/how-can-i-remove-breakpoint-ntdlldbgbreakpoint0x1-in-windbg)  but there is no clairy response :(
I'm debugging a program (c++) that crash, it'me who put the crash line code (_invalide_parameter)
When I tape: **.exr -1** in Windbg to show the last event causes the crash (there is just one event), it show me

```
00000000`006bfbd8 00000000`775d7ef8 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : ntdll!DbgBreakPoint
```

Me I don't care for that, I hope that show me a line where are:  **kernel32UnhandledExceptionFilter**. Yes, this line exist and i can dispaly it by **~*kv** command
There is a way to skip  hard-coded breakpoint  **ntdll!DbgBreakPoint** because the command **bl**, **bc *** and **bd *** do anythings?

Thanks for you.

If needed: Win7 x64, VS2008, C++, Windbg 64byts, Symbols not loaded, just defaults symbols (it' another history here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to modify the code in memory, because is in the code where the breakpoint is.

1. First, locate the function in the stack trace that is calling to `DbgBreakPoint()`. (Be sure you locate the right function in the right module).
2. Edit in memory the code to avoid the call (for example, substituting the `push` and `call` commands by `nop`). You can do that with the **a** command.